# SQL Query - select all from one table with matching records in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to select the values form one table and if they have matching values in another

```
SELECT *
FROM me_cards AS c LEFT JOIN
     me_member_cards AS m
     ON m.cardID = c.id AND m.userID = 2 AND m.status = 'Collecting' LEFT JOIN
     me_decks AS d
     ON d.deckName = c.deckName 
WHERE c.deckName = 'Couples'
ORDER BY cardNumber
```

Now the problem i'm having is if there are multiple records in the second table it gives mutlitple records

I have the two tables

- me_cards - has the list of cards in
- me_member_cards - has the list the member has.

If the card appears multiple times in member cards then the query returns all rows, i want it to return all the cards and if the user has that card.
Current, id the user has the card then the details from me_member_cards show, if they don't it shows as null

```
Table details
CREATE TABLE `me_cards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deckName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cardNumber` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `me_cards` (`id`, `deckName`, `cardNumber`) VALUES
(202, 'Couples', '01'),
(203, 'Couples', '02'),
(204, 'Couples', '03'),
(205, 'Couples', '04'),
(206, 'Couples', '05'),
(207, 'Couples', '06'),
(208, 'Couples', '07'),
(209, 'Couples', '08'),
(210, 'Couples', '09'),
(211, 'Couples', '10'),
(212, 'Couples', '11'),
(213, 'Couples', '12'),
(214, 'Couples', '13'),
(215, 'Couples', '14'),
(216, 'Couples', '15'),
(217, 'Couples', '16'),
(218, 'Couples', '17'),
(219, 'Couples', '18'),
(220, 'Couples', '19'),
(221, 'Couples', '20')

CREATE TABLE `me_decks` (
  `deckName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckDescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckCategory` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckSubCat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckType` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckFeatures` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckWorth` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `deckCardAmount` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `deckURLName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deckReleased` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `deckOrder` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `deckCard` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '01'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `me_decks`
--

INSERT INTO `me_decks` (`deckName`, `deckDescription`, `deckCategory`, `deckSubCat`, `deckType`, `deckFeatures`, `deckWorth`, `deckCardAmount`, `deckURLName`, `deckReleased`, `deckOrder`, `deckCard`) VALUES
('Couples', 'Senshi & Shitennout Pair', 'Puzzle', 'Manga', 'Puzzle', '', 1, 20, 'couples', 1, 999, '14');

CREATE TABLE `me_member_cards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cardID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'undefined'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `me_member_cards`
--

    INSERT INTO `me_member_cards` (`id`, `userID`, `cardID`, `status`, `id`, `deckName`, `cardNumber`) VALUES
    (29, 2, 212, 'Collecting', 212, 'Couples', '11'),
    (80, 2, 221, 'Collecting', 221, 'Couples', '20'),
    (81, 2, 221, 'Collecting', 221, 'Couples', '20'),
    (83, 2, 221, 'Collecting', 221, 'Couples', '20'),
    (101, 2, 221, 'Collecting', 221, 'Couples', '20');
```

What i am getting is

```
id    deckName   cardNumber   id     userID   cardID   status       deckName   deckDescription            deckCategory   deckSubCat   deckType   deckFeatures   deckWorth   deckCardAmount   deckURLName   deckReleased   deckOrder   deckCard
202   Couples    01           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
203   Couples    02           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
204   Couples    03           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
205   Couples    04           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
206   Couples    05           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
207   Couples    06           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
208   Couples    07           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
209   Couples    08           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
210   Couples    09           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
211   Couples    10           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
212   Couples    11           29     2        212      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
213   Couples    12           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
214   Couples    13           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
215   Couples    14           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
216   Couples    15           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
217   Couples    16           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
218   Couples    17           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
219   Couples    18           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
220   Couples    19           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
221   Couples    20           81     2        221      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
221   Couples    20           83     2        221      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
221   Couples    20           101    2        221      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
221   Couples    20           80     2        221      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14
```

Add what i want is

```
id    deckName   cardNumber   id     userID   cardID   status       deckName   deckDescription            deckCategory   deckSubCat   deckType   deckFeatures   deckWorth   deckCardAmount   deckURLName   deckReleased   deckOrder   deckCard
202   Couples    01           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
203   Couples    02           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
204   Couples    03           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
205   Couples    04           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
206   Couples    05           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
207   Couples    06           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
208   Couples    07           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
209   Couples    08           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
210   Couples    09           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
211   Couples    10           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
212   Couples    11           29     2        212      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
213   Couples    12           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
214   Couples    13           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
215   Couples    14           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
216   Couples    15           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
217   Couples    16           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
218   Couples    17           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
219   Couples    18           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
220   Couples    19           NULL   NULL     NULL     NULL         Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14      
221   Couples    20           81     2        221      Collecting   Couples    Senshi & Shitennout Pair   Puzzle         Manga        Puzzle                    1           20               couples       1              999         14
```

What i ultimately want to do is get all the cards in the deck, if the user has the card then display it, if they don't then show a placeholder

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: We will need to know which columns are coming from which tables

Comment: what about the id (there are 4 different values for 221) in your result? where does that go if you keep only one row for 221?

Comment: Provide sample input data table wise in text form and expected result based on that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: its mysql. the id doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know for every card in the deck, whether a particular user has this card, and if so show `me_member_cards` details. The problem is that a user can have a card multiple times, but you still want to show only one result row for the card. So you must decide *which* `me_member_cards` data to show in that case. Here is an example where I show the maximum `status` per card:

```
select *
from me_decks d
join me_cards c on c.deckname = d.deckname
left join
(
  select cardid, max(status) as max_status
  from me_member_cards
  where userid = 2 
  and status = 'Collecting'
  group by cardid
) mc on mc.cardid = c.id
where d.deckname = 'Couples';
```

Comment: thanks, modified slightly but got it doing what i want

select d.deckName, c.cardNumber, mc.userID, d.deckURLName, d.deckCategory
   from me_decks d
   join me_cards c on c.deckname = d.deckname
   left join
   (
    select userID, cardID
    from me_member_cards
    where userid = :userID
    and status = 'Collecting'
    group by cardid
   ) mc on mc.cardid = c.id
   where d.deckname = :deckName

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. This is a general answer, while in your case there is no actual data to retrieve from `me_member_cards` (you only select `userID` from it, which is a constant in your query). So a mere `IN` clause would suffice here.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo... Something like this?

Returns all from Cards where there is a member with the card, but only once. Includes columns from Decks

```
select c.*, d.*
from me_cards c
inner join me_decks d
  on d.deckName = c.deckName 
where c.id in (select m.cardid 
               from me_member_cards m 
               where m.status = 'collecting')
and c.deckname = 'Couples'
```

EDIT:

Ok, so...

```
select *
from me_cards c
left join (select distinct m.card_id
           from me_member_cards m
           where m.userID = 2 
           and m.status = 'Collecting'
          ) m2
     ON m2.cardID = c.id 
left join me_decks d
     ON d.deckName = c.deckName 
WHERE c.deckName = 'Couples'
```

If you need more info from the me_member_cards table, you can left join it again with a shiny new alias

Comment: its only returning the rows the user has, not all the rows